# Cut <br/>-Tags from String end

Tags: java, regex, string

I am currently developing a Web-Application using Java EE where I'm using a Rich-Javascript-Editor (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf). 
As the user can easily add too many linebreaks that will be convertet to linebreak-tags, I need to remove all these Tags from the end of a String.

Is there an elegant way of using Regex to accomplish this?

An example String would be:

```
"This is a test <b>bold</b><br/><br/>"
```

Where obviously the last two tags have to be removed.

Thank you in advance for any help

Best Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String s = "This is a test <b>bold</b><br/><br/>";
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(\\s*<[Bb][Rr]\\s*/?>)+\\s*$", "");
// s2 = "This is a test <b>bold</b>";
```

Note that it will also remove trailing whitespace; you can delete the final `\\s*` if you don't want that.

Comment: Replacing the "replace" with "replaceAll", this works perfectly, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple line of Java code to remove all instances of the substring `"<br/>"` from the end of a string `myString`:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(<br/>)+$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for most cases.

This regex considers most of scenarios where different forms for `<br>` occurs

All of the following are valid `<br>` statements :

```
-<br>
-<br/>
-<br />
-<br / >
-<br/ >
-<br //// >
```

This regex identifies all such forms of `<br>`

```
string = string.replaceAll("<br[\\s/]*>", "");
```

Comment: provide an explanation for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.Its working for me

```
myString =myString .replaceAll("<br/>", "");
```